# HtmlUnit selenium python Errno 111

Tags: python, django, selenium, htmlunit

I'm trying to use selenium with `HtmlUnit` in my `Django` app. This is my procedure:

I start in background: java -jar `selenium-server-standalone-2.27.0.jar` bg

I use this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

url = "www.google.com"
driver = WebDriver("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
driver.get(url)
text = driver.page_source
...
```

My problem is that I get always `urlopen` error [Errno 111] Connection refused". Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run your code without errors with the last version of the stand alone server and the selenium python bindings (2.31 at the moment).

I usually start the server in background:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar &
```

Then starting from version 2 of the python bindings your can use the simpler:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Just make sure the background server is actually running, test it by opening a browser and typing the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
```